# Проблема с получением Let'sEncrypt. Ошибка 404 при проверке файла

Tags: веб-сервер, ssl, letsencrypt

Пытался получить ssl сертификат для сайта. Для проверки прав на домен выбрал вариант загрузки файла на сервер. Для этого в корневом каталоге была создана папка **.well-known** и в ней папка **acme-challenge**. Далее загрузил файл без расширения в папку acme-challenge и при попытке проверить ее наличие выходит ошибка 404, при том что файл лежит в каталоге и права выставлены 755 и 644 соответственно.

В чем может быть проблема не подскажите?

p.s был второй вариант проверки прав на домен с помощью DNS-записи, но сайт требует выставить TTL 1, а кривой хостинг, которым я пользуюсь, позволяет выставить минимум только 120. Так что этот вариант точно отпадает

Comment: 1) проверь доступ к файлу по прямому url в браузере или wget c другой машины
2) проверь настройки своего сервера ( часто все запросы к домены направляют на индексный файл)

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что пользуетесь бесплатными сертификатами `sslforfree`.
Для того, чтобы установить сертификат Вам необходимо:
 1. Выбрать вариант подтверждения через файл. 
 2. Скачать сформированный файл.
 3. Выставить в `apache2` или `nginx`(Смотря чем пользуетесь) направление на порт `80` и доступ к Вашему сайту (без сертификата). Перезапустить службу.
 4. Прописать `DNS` до Вашего сервера. 
 5. Проверить работоспособность сайта на `http`(Без сертификата).
 6. В корневой папке сайта создать папку `.well-known`.
 7. В ней создать ещё одну папку `acme-challenge`.
 8. Поместить в эту папку скаченный файл. 
 9. Проверить путь до файла. Пример: `https.yousite.ru/.well-known/acme-challenge/odshgpbwepvwg[oieahfo[ihafuhuihiu2h390f2839ur08` (Где `odshgpbwepvwg[oieahfo[ihafuhuihiu2h390f2839ur08` - это скаченный файл. 
 У Вас должна открыться страница по данному адресу с каким-то текстом. 
 10. После этого скачиваете формирующиеся сертификаты (сертификат, связка и ключ) в папку `ssl`.
 11. Прописываете в `apache2` или `nginx` запись на 443 порт и указываете пути до Вашего сертификата, связки и ключа. Перезапускаете службу. 
 После этого у Вас всё будет работать корректно.

Comment: Да, верно, пытаюсь сделать на сайте sslforfree. В том то и дело, что при проверке по ссылке выходит 404 ошибка. Если закинуть файл в каталог выше, т.е. в .well-known, то файл доступен. Создаю в .well-known любую другую папку и закидываю туда файл и он доступен. Проблема именно в acme-challenge будто

Comment: @АлиЖакупов. Внимательно проверьте каждую букву тогда ) И такое бывает. Должно работать. Сам пользовался много раз подобными сертификатами. Попробуйте скопировать прям название этой папки и добавить.

Comment: я это все уже тысячи раз проверял. Фишка в том, что если создать в каталоге .well-known папку с другим названием и туда закинуть файл - он доступен, а в acme-challenge выдает 404. Только что проверил error.log и увидел там ошибку непонятную openat() "/usr/local/mgr5/www/letsencrypt/GZqNUvOHumabnlDo8i-bZlPQ_hxG3p_8Ambzs1mQMAs" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 99.99.99.99, server: site.kz, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/GZqNUvOHumabnlDo8i-bZlPQ_hxG3p_8Ambzs1mQMAs HTTP/1.1", host: "site.kz"

Comment: @АлиЖакупов Ага, теперь понял. Покажите, пожалуйста `nginx`. Скорее всего там прописан `alias`